# iPhone Create UIButton in IB for custom UIView

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton

I have a custom UIView (created without InterfaceBuilder) in my app. And I want to insert an UIButton into it, but I don't want to create the button prorammatically.
So I want to create UIButton in Interface Builder and then put it into my view.

My first steps were:
1) Create XIB from "Empty" template
2) Drag RoundRect button from Objects Library onto this XIB
3) Save XIB as "MyButton.xib"

were these steps correct? and what's next?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO connect the View and the UIButton from your XIB-File to your custom UIView-Class.

After that creates the click-method for this button and have fun :)

Comment: How do I load MyButton.xib? And how do I extract UIButton after loading?

Comment: Initialise your UIViewController with the Method "initWithNibName" and setup your XIB-Filename. [`UIViewController Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName:bundle:) To work with the UIButton you have to connect the Button from the XIB with an property of your UIViewController.

Comment: But in my application I haven't got any UIViewController. I only have UIView created manually.

Comment: To show a UIView you need a UIViewController, this Class has an property "view" of the type UIView. Do you have any experience in iPhone-programming? Possibly you start with an [`beginner-tutorial?`](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/07/03/beignner-iphone-sdk-hello-world-tutorial-first-application/)

Comment: To show UIView I have only to add it as a sub-view to another (visible) view. There's absolutely no need in UIViewController :)